# mod rewrite not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site where my pages are generated dynamically. I want to change the url from:

`http://www.mydomain.com/library.php?id=13`

to something like:

`http://www.mydomain.com/13.html`

I am using this Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /library.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I click on the link the page goes to this url:

`www.mydomain.com/library.php?id=13`

But the strange part is when I browse to `www.mydomain.com/13.html` the link is working.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should mark Walialu answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the links that are generated in the **library.php** files to your new defined format :)